# Jquery form doesn't show submission message on web server but it shows submission message on local host

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

i am messed up with a strange problem. My Form works fine on local machine but when i upload this to some web server, it does not work fine . Without uploading online, when i add some values and click Submit. It shows ThankYou message. But When it is uploaded, after adding any value, when some values are added and Submit pressed, values are entered to database but it doesn't show Thankyou message rather it just remains as it is. Please, suggest some solution. What should i do to make it work fine online ?? Should i send the single HTML file that contains the form ? Have a look at form here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/33855631/lon_dec/form.htm

i also tried it by uploading to different servers like bluehost etc but no solution.

Comment: Is this cross-domain scripting, e.g. form hosted on domainA and submission goes to domainB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're indeed making a cross-domain request (to http://www.londondeclaration.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php), which your browser doesn't allow. Either host the front-end and back-end on the same domain, or (if that's not possible) host a proxy to the external source on your own domain.

Answer (score 0):

As @PPvG already mentioned this looks like cross-domain scripting. In general, it is possible to perform croos-domain scripting, but you must set the according HTTP headers as specified [here](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy). That's what happens in detail:

1. user accesses a web page on DomainA including some JavaScript (i.e. jQuery)
2. user submits button and jQuery fires request to your server on DomainB
3. result is returned to the users browser, but per plicy *the client forbids* the scripts from DomainA to examine the response retrieved from DomainB. It's important to understand that security is enforced on the client.

**How to solve the problem:** Your application on DomainB must set the correct **HTTP response header**, so that the browser allows your jQuery script from DomainA to work with the response from DomainB:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:DomainA
```

This may still not work in all situations. I.e. Internet Explorer does enforce fairly rigid rules when it comes to HTTPS, if I remember correcly cookie management is a problem as well.

EDIT: In Google Chrome you can easily see that this is the problem:

[image]