# Accessing a image stored on remote machine

Tags: jakarta-ee

In our application user can link a logo to the application and the dimensions of this image will be stored in the database along with image url, upon successful operation the image will be displayed on the page on the reload.
Our problem is when a user tries to link a image stored on his local intranet server then application is not able to access that image, probably due to security reason.

We are using a HttpClient to access the image. It works well for all other cases except which is specified above. Please suggest any workaround.

Comment: Is there a proxy server involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `HttpClient` to access the external image server-side (in your Java EE application), this will never work as you simply do not have access to the user's intranet. There are 2 solutions:

1. store the image itself on your server as well and stream it to the client - user is required to upload the file to your server.
2. store link to the image in your application and generate your HTML accordingly, e.g. `<img src="http://user.intranet.com/logo.gif`.

The latter solution may introduce security problems when it comes to HTTPS (TLS) and cross-domain resources.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have another doubt on this. Is this possible to access the images from client site using javascript.

Comment: Technically speaking - yes it is possible, but you may run into cross-domain scripting issues: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766594/jquery-form-doesnt-show-submission-message-on-web-server-but-it-shows-submissio/7766719#7766719).