# AJAX call to internal server works in IE but not in other browsers

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm calling a server site on our internal server. This domain looks like this:

```
http://server.domain:12345/x.html
```

Now, with IE this works just fine, I'm getting the data. (My problem there is that IE caches the website after the first call forever, but never mind).

Now, if I'm trying to do exactly the same in Firefox, it won't work, the same in Google Chrome.

Firebug says this:

```
Answer-Header

Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  109
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Keep-Alive  timeout=5000
Server  AbWeb Version SRSG 1.34
Set-Cookie  sessionkey=80da7dfe-1c9c-4460-9592-3ce55cecb379

Request-Header

Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection  keep-alive
Host    server.domain:12345
Origin  http://otherserver.domain
Referer http://otherserver.domain/test/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
```

Chrome says this:

```
X XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://server.domain:12345/x.html. Origin http://otherservere.domain is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
server.domain:12345/x.html

X Failed to load resource
```

Comment: Is it about Javascript calls or whole pages?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm just calling this page via AJAX and this is the error I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you perform cross-domain JavaScript calls. The target server must set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` HTTP header. In your case the server `http://server.domain` must set a header like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://otherserver.domain
```

I do not know why it works for IE, it may have to do with your security domains as your just working in the intranet.

See another example:

- [Jquery form doesn't show submission message on web server but it shows submission message on local host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766594/jquery-form-doesnt-show-submission-message-on-web-server-but-it-shows-submissio)