# I am trying to consume wsdl soap based service by jquery ajax method but I am getting one error No "Access Control Allow Origin" error

Tags: jquery, soap

I have a URL for a webservice `http://ediblesoftware.com/esxml30/esxml.wsdl?op=Request` and I need to pass input like this below.
This is my ajax function and  I am trying to consume service here.

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    data: params,
    crossDomain: true,
    url: servUrl,
    contentType: "text/xml",
    dataType: 'xml',
    success:successResponse,
    error: errorResponse
});
```

Can anybody help what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766594/jquery-form-doesnt-show-submission-message-on-web-server-but-it-shows-submissio

Comment: What do you are using on backend? Tomcat? if so, try to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526146/how-to-enable-cors-in-apache-tomcat